# On Info Window Click in iphone

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to show a small window on the click of info window in iphone google maps. I want that when the user will tap on the marker, info window will appear. And on the tap of that info window, another window should appear.
In android, there is a OnInfoWindowClickListener method.
What we have in iOS like that ?

Comment: u mean callOutView of annotaion ???

Comment: I found that after a little search. It is GMSMapViewDelegate's method  didTapInfoWindowOfMarker :)

Answer (score 2):

where you adding Map,add

```
 mapView_.delegate=self;
```

then use this

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{

   //info window tapped

}
```

Comment: hey man..you know how to set frame for google map ??

Comment: Create a CGRect with the required frame dimensions and set the MapView frame with method `mapWithFrame:` and then add the mapview as main subview. Below is the code which explains all.                   `CGRect fr= CGRectMake(0, 44, 768, 960);
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:fr camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView_];`

Answer (score 0):

in iOS a delegate method will be called in the case the user taps on the info window. Here is the documentation of the delegate.

```
/**
 * Called after a marker's info window has been tapped.
 */
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
    didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(id<GMSMarker>)marker;
```

As parameters you will receive the mapView instance and the object of the info window's marker. Don't forget to include the GMSMapViewDelegate.